# Minor Upgrade in Wix (Not a Patch)

Tags: wix, upgrade

I am trying to implement a Minor Upgrade (not a patch) using WiX. I am not sure if there are many tutorials or samples for this, including the steps to uninstall it. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2):

First of all there is very little benefit in using a minor upgrade because basically you make another MSI file that is the same as the existing one except for the updated files you want to update. The ProductCode is the same. It is applied with a command line such as:

msiexec /I [path to msi] REINSTALLMODE=vomus REINSTALL=ALL

There's really no advantage to this because you might as well make a major upgrade MSI which is a fresh install for new clients and it happens to upgrade any older existing installed products, using the same command line.

The basic documentation is here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370037(v=vs.85).aspx

explaining the ProductCode, ProductVersion rules. You also need to follow component rules in a minor upgrade, as with a patch.